# Could someone please explain counting to me?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I'm taking a Discrete Math class and I understand the concepts behind counting, but I feel like I'm having to learn how to tackle word problems all over again.  I can't seem to figure out how to discern which tools I should be using.  Maybe I don't understand how the rule of sum, rule of product, permutations and combinations relate to one another, so it makes it difficult to figure out what I should be using for a particular scenario. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167313/difference-between-permutation-and-combination/167319#167319 could help

Comment: Yeah, that helps some. Any resources similar to this helps. I'm a visual learner. Thank you!

Comment: It can be a little bewildering at the beginning. After solving a number of problems, you will find that there are useful patterns.

Comment: I figured it was like most math I have taken where if you spend time with it you start to see certain patterns, but I really seem to be struggling with this.  Maybe because the terminology is so new.  Thing is I really want to learn this stuff because the class is fascinating but curiosity only gets me so far especially since the material is being covered quickly.

Comment: One important part to learning to count is to understand special cases well and then, eventually, be able to recognize the patterns in those simple cases.  For example, you will eventually learn that ${4 \choose 2} = 6$ and you can see this by writing out all 12 possible ways of choosing two ordered letters from $\{A,B,C,D\}$ -- AB, AC, AD, BA, BC, BD, CA, CB, CD, DA, DB, DC -- and then grouping them into 6 groups of two based on which two letters get chosen (not caring about the order anymore).  That's the essence for the more general formula ${n \choose k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$. (cont.)

Comment: Most people learn this material best by going from simple examples to general formulas.  When you see a general formula you don't understand, first understand it in simple cases, then try to generalize the patterns you see to understand the general formula.

Comment: I feel like the professor launched into more difficult cases right from the get go, which had my head spinning. I agree though. I wish I could find some simple cases that have a visual element to them like the one that Jean-Sebastien referenced.

Answer (score 2):

So this is a problem that can be tackled at a huge number of different levels. People write books on counting, with the purpose of explaining counting, and this discipline is called combinatorics.

But to answer your question about sums and products and permutations and combinations.

When you have the opportunity to make a single choice from one of two set, you sum the cardinalities of the two sets. This makes sense, because you're trying to find one from the collection of the two, seen as a single sets. For example, how many ways can you pick one person from a class of 4 boys and 3 girls?

$7$. Because $3+4 = 7$.

And for products, if you're making a sequence of independent choices, you can multiply them, because for each choice you make first, you can make one possibility from the second set of choices. So to pick one boy and one girl from our class of 4 and 3 boys and girls, we have

$$4\cdot 3= 12$$

To find the ways of permuting something, we use the product rule we just described. A permutation is a rearrangement of an ordered tuple, so we need to number the ways of ordering, say $n$, things. We can set this up as subsequent choices. Our first choice is which of our $n$ goes in the first spot, the second is which of the $n-1$ go in the second, and so on. Because of this product rule, we can multiply this, and get the the number of permutations of an $n$ element set is 
$$n(n-1)\cdot\cdots(3)(2)(1) = n!$$

And for combinations, we use this when we're trying to find the number of subsets of a certain size of a, say $n$ element, set. There's an easy way of thinking of the formula for this. If you want to pick $k$ items from an $n$ element set, create 'boxes' like such

$$[\circ, \circ,  ... , \circ][\circ, \circ,  ... , \circ]$$

With $k$ spaces in the first and $n-k$ in the second, so there are $k$ total. Now we want to find a way to arrange the $n$ elements into these spaces, which by our previous discussion is $n!$. But wait! We count subsets in different orders as different subsets, which we can't allow. So we make it such that if all of the elements are the same in the first box, then two different permutations give the same combination. Well, for each way of putting $k$ in the first box, and $n-k$ in the second, there are $k!$ to arrange the first box, and $(n-k)!$ ways to arrange the second per our previous discussion. So we divide our way of distributing the $n$ elements into the boxes by the number of distributions each desired thing we want to count takes up from these, and get that our result is
$$\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$$

And this encompasses the basics of combinatorics. But you can learn much more from books. If your class has a textbook, I recommend reading that. If not, there are a number of options. You might want to research your own, but I highly reccomend Graham/Knuth/Patashnik, *Concrete mathematics*.

Comment: Thank you for the book recommendation. I'm thinking my unfamiliarity with the jargon is also playing a role in some of my difficulties.  I guess I could make flash cards to help with that.

Comment: @DanielRust, yes I did mean set. The operations that take two elements from boys and girls and produces another one is best left out of discussions of classrooms.

Comment: @lsward That would work. Also, the names aren't simply chosen at random. They makes sense in context. For example, a permutation is exactly what it means in english - a rearrangement. And the number of those you can usually rederive every time you think about it until it becomes second nature. The same for combination. You are combining $k$ elements from $n$ into one subset. So if you get familiar with why those numbers are what they are, it should eventually be easy.

Comment: Do you know of any books that have more of a visual element to them? I'm more of a visual learner and have found pictorial examples of even simplified cases help me out.

Comment: Hmm. I can't think of any off the top of my head, but they probably exist. But you might try the incredibly useful strategy of drawing pictures yourself of everything that it might help with. This is not only useful now, but especially when you read higher level texts which rarely have pictures, and if you're in the habit of drawing pictures to help understand, then you're a step ahead already.